# How to bind objects to firebase inside an array?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

When you have an array of objects, how do you go about binding the changes of an object to firebase?

data looks like this:

```
[{ title: "Do Something", Due: "1425121200000", assignedTo: "Bill", description: "Do something", $id: wqejkkjebiewdf},
 { title: "Do Something else", Due: "1425121200000",  assignedTo: "Jim", description: "Do something else", $id: owenuwefwfliu}]
```

js:

```
var todos = this;
todos.tasks = [];
var todoRef = new Firebase(FB + "/tasks/" + CurrentFarm);
var todoArray = $firebase(todoRef).$asArray();
todoArray.$loaded(todos.tasks = todoArray);
```

html to show todos:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in todo.tasks | orderBy:'when'| filter: {done: true}">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.done" ng-change="todo.taskDone(task)">
<span ng-repeat="users in task.users">{{getName(users)}} </span> 
<span> {{task.title}} </span>
<span> {{task.when | date:"EEEE, d MMMM, y"}} </span>
<input ng-click="editTask()" type="button"  value="Edit">
</div>
```

html for editing a todo.  Note that I removed certain inputs from this code like date pickers etc to make it more readable.

```
<div  ng-show="editTaskMenu">
    <form  novalidate>
        <input ng-model="task.title" type="text" value="{{task.title}}">
        <textarea ng-model="task.description" value="{{task.description}}"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Done" ng-click="finishedEditing()">
    </form>
</div>
```

The changes bind to the array in angular but do not get updated in firebase.  From what I can tell there is no way to do three way binding with an array, so what is the work around here?

Comment: Please also show the *relevant code* of your solution, so we know how you've already tried to solve this problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There is no need for a workaround. 3-way data bindings are simply a convenience. Call $save on the items when they are changed and they will be synchronized back to Firebase. Starting with a read-through of [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html) will save you a great deal of thrashing on fundamentals like this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added more code for you, hope it helps.  I haven't got an attempted solution there but all I could think of was Kato's solution or similar which is to $save each input on the object individually on change.  But I wanted to know the best way to do  it since I thought it would be a commonly used thing.

Comment: I have an application where I use `$asArray` to show a list of items (so `ng-repeat` over them) and then allow editing of the selected object's properties through three-way binding (with `$asObject` and `$bindTo`). As usual: the bet way is the one that works for you use-case(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularFire accomplishes three-way binding, which is what you're looking for.

Take a look at the [quick-start guide.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html)

---

*From the quick-start guide:*

To sync data as an object:

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);
app.controller("SampleCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/data");
  // synchronize the object with a three-way data binding
  var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
  syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");
});
```

Source: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-objects

When you do that, `syncObject` will be bound to `$scope.data`, and any changes to `$scope.data` will update `syncObject`, and hence the data at the firebase location.

But what you want is `$firebaseArray` like so:

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);
app.controller("SampleCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/messages");
  // create a synchronized array for use in our HTML code
  $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);
});
```

Source: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-arrays

---

Here is the full [AngularFire API documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html)

Comment: Yes I have synced it `.$asArray()` And when an object is added to the array it syncs it to firebase which is great.  But what I am asking is how do you sync the changes of an object within that array to firebase? ie updating a value of an object within that array rather than adding a new item to the array iteself.

Comment: You'd do that by *also* binding that specific object using `$asObject` as Sinan shows. Don't worry about the data transfer, Firebase is intelligent enough to transfer the data only once even when the same node is bound both with `$asArray` and `$asObject`.

Comment: Alternately, rather than setting up $asObject, you can just use $save() on the array, for the specific items with changes.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you mean bind the same ref as the `.$asArray` using `$asObject` or do you mean bind each of the array items as objects?

Comment: @Kato Is there a way to detect changes in the object itself or would it be best to use `ng-change` on each of the inputs?  There is about 6 inputs for each object so I was just concerned it wouldn't be very maintainable code.

Comment: check out AngularFire `$watch`. For `$FirebaseArray`:  https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-watchcb-context and for `$FirebaseObject`: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-watchcallback-context